# locally vs universally administered MAC address?

Tags: network, mac-address

1. Difference between locally and universally administered MAC address?
2. What is the purpose of locally administered MAC address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Difference between locally and universally administered MAC address?

LAA has 2nd least significant bit in first octet set to `1`, UAA has `0`.

> 2. What is the purpose of locally administered MAC address?

Some (few) users seem to need their own MAC addressing scheme. I don't think there's a specific application for LAA.

Comment: Thanks @Zaac67. Can't i set least significant bit in first octet to 0?

Comment: Of course you can. The LSB set to `1` indicates a group address (broadcast or multicast); `0` is unicast.